# display image with relationships laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I want to get the first image for each product to display it into a thumbnails home page.

My code is wrong because the relationships in the iteration of a product displayed all images of one product for one thumbnails, that is ugly :).

So what i want is to display the first image for each products, because i'm using the multiple images upload.

```
 Route::get('/home', function () {
    $product = Product::with('image')->get();
    dd($product);
    $image = DB::table('images')->get();
    return view('frontend.home')->with(['products' => $product,'image' => $image]);
})->name('shop.home');
```

At this point it doesn't work because i need to display the first image per product, i have tried this :

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<img class="bd-placeholder-img"src="{{ asset("storage/{$product->image->path}") }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: So... Each product has many images? And all products have at least one image?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't get a single record form Eager loading a one to many relationship, **but**
you can define another `hasOne` relationship to get a single image record for the product:

```
public function oneImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
}
```

Then call in controller:

```
$product = Product::with('oneImage')->get();
```

And it should display one image per product.

*Tip: in one to many relationships, names should be plural, so in your case you should name the function `images` not `image`*.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Product
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);//don't forget to import
}

public function previewImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Image::class);//don't forget to import
}
```

In route file

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $products = Product::with('previewImage')->get();
    return view('frontend.home', compact('products'));
})->name('shop.home');
```

In blade:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<img class="bd-placeholder-img"src="{{ asset('storage/' . $product->previewImage->path) }}">
@endforeach
```

I put several aspects here using some of [best practice and convention in framework](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices). Study it and adapt in your application.

Answer (score 0):

// Product

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

In route file

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('index', [$products => 'products']));
});
```

In blade:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $product->images[0]->path) }}">
@endforeach
```